npm publish not reading updated version
I'm setting up a new npm library to be published in a private registry. I have these scripts:
    "build": "tsc --p ./tsconfig-build.json && vite build",
    "release": "commit-and-tag-version --no-verify",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run release && npm run build"

The problem is that, even though release effectively runs before publishing when I do npm publish, the package that gets published has the previous version. So the timeline goes something like this:

My current package.json has "version": "0.0.10"
I run npm publish
Triggers prepublishOnly that runs npm run release && npm run build
commit-and-tag-version correctly bumps package.json and package-lock.json and tags my repo with v0.0.11
vite build bundles the library
publish packs my library as my-library@0.0.10, ignoring the recent bump triggered during prepublishOnly

Everything works as expected if I delete the prepublishOnly script and manually do:
npm run release && npm run build && npm publish

Is this the expected behavior of prepublishOnly? Any suggestions on how to make this work properly, without having a custom publish script like:
    "publishLibrary" : "npm run release && npm run build && npm publish"


See npm/cli#2756.

Thanks @jonrsharpe I googled but couldn't find that one. It makes sense that it's a bug but it's discouraging that it was reported for version 7.5.5 in 2021 and it hasn't been fixed in version 10.5.0 in 2024...
